# SQL Server dynamic distinct value to column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have 2 tables, `campaign` and `mission`, where each mission is linked to only one campaign.

Then for each campaign, I can define many extra attributes, each attribute is linked to only one campaign.

For example, `campaign1` will have an extra attribute `attr1`, `campaign2` will have another one but with same name `attr1`, and `campaign3` has a different attribute `attr3`.

For each mission, I can add an extra value for each extra attribute of her campaign.

When I retrieve the data, I want in column the missionId but also the maximum of campaign attribute based on my query (one if there is a filter on one campaign, many if there are more). So the campaignAttr label in column that contain the missionAttr value in row.

I read a bit about pivot but I'm not sure it can help here... Not even sure this is possible at all, so if someone knows how to achieve this I would be very graceful :)

Sample of structure and data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bd329/3/0
(Even a result as JSON would be fine for me)

Expected result:

[image]

I want to achieve this to be able to display this table in frontend and let the user sort and filter by the campaign extra attributes.

Comment: If you are including sample data and expected results please include them in the question, not an off-site resource. The link you have provided does not load for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help:

```
SELECT MissionID, CampaignId, Attr1, Attr2, Attr3
FROM
    (SELECT MissionID, CampaignId, Label, Value FROM MissionAttr m
     JOIN CampaignAttr c ON m.CampaignAttrid = c.id) AS Source
PIVOT(
      MAX(Value)
      for Label IN (Attr1, Attr2, Attr3)
)AS pivottable;
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mg4yq9Sr)

Comment: not exactly but i figure out something based on this sample, thx!